# Android to PC TCP communication working only on Emulator

Tags: c#, android, tcp, ip, loopback-address

I have a requirement to implement an android application to communicate with a `c#` application on a PC over `TCP` (wifi). I have followed this -

https://workspaces.codeproject.com/dhl_hh/android-how-to-communicate-with-net-application-vi

tutorial to implement the solution which uses the `eneter` library.

This works just fine on the emulator as the IP used for `C#` application is

```
IDuplexInputChannel anInputChannel
            = aMessaging.CreateDuplexInputChannel("tcp://127.0.0.1:8060/");
```

and the IP used for the `Android` app is

```
IDuplexOutputChannel anOutputChannel
        = aMessaging.createDuplexOutputChannel("tcp://10.0.2.2:8060/");
```

However, when i transfer the android app to actual device and try to transmit data over `wifi` the C# application does not display the string transferred from the mobile device as shown in the tutorial.

The fixes I tried was,

- Kept the C# IP as is (127.0.0.1) and changed the android IP to PC's IP (192.168.137.1) where the c# app is running.
- **The fix that works :** Changed the C# IP to the PC's actual IP (192.168.137.1) and changed the IP address of the android app to the actual IP of the android device (192.168.137.1).
- **FYI** : I did not change the port number

These fixes did not fix the issue and I have no clue on how to do this. I was trying many solutions for few days now as I am a novice to the filed of `tcp` programming.

I would really appreciate you experts advice on how to fix this issue.

You help s greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

**PS**

- Actual IP of PC (with the C# program) - `192.168.137.1`
- Actual IP of the android device (with the android app) - `192.168.137.14`

**Logcat output**

```
05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): ~  1 eneter.messaging.endpoints.typedmessages.DuplexTypedMessageSender.sendRequestMessage DuplexTypedMessageSender<MyResponse, MyRequest> atached to the duplex output channel '' failed to send the request message because it is not attached to any duplex output channel.
05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): ~  1 net.client.AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivity.onSendRequest Sending the message failed.

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): Exception:

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): java.lang.IllegalStateException: DuplexTypedMessageSender<MyResponse, MyRequest> atached to the duplex output channel '' failed to send the request message because it is not attached to any duplex output channel.

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): eneter.messaging.endpoints.typedmessages.DuplexTypedMessageSender.sendRequestMessage(DuplexTypedMessageSender.java:67)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): net.client.AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivity.onSendRequest(AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivity.java:120)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): net.client.AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivity.access$1(AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivity.java:111)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): net.client.AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivity$2.onClick(AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivity.java:160)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17084)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

05-29 12:49:17.988: E/EneterMessaging(1792): ==========
```

Comment: Have you made sure your PC's Windows Firewall allowed that connection?

Comment: That was correct: "Kept the C# IP as is (127.0.0.1) and changed the android IP to PC's IP (192.168.137.1) where the c# app is running."

Comment: You should consider turning off your firewall or any anti-virus applications in your PC

Comment: @JustAndrei Thank you for the reply.. Ohh I forgot to check that.. I will check it and post back :)

Comment: @Coderji Thank you for the reply :) i will turn off firewall and post back :)

Comment: @JustAndrei I tried disabling the firewall and virus guard but still no result. I have attached the `logcat` and updated the question :)

Comment: @Coderji I tried disabling the firewall and virus guard but that did not work. I uploaded the `logcat` output on the question and would be great if you could provide a solution from that :)

Comment: @JustAndrei Your idea of stopping the firewall did the trick! However, The solution that worked was - **Changed the C# IP to the PC's actual IP (192.168.137.1) and changed the IP address of the android app to the actual IP of the android device (192.168.137.1).** . But still it was your solution that lead me to the answer and would be great if you could post it as an answer :)

Comment: @Coderji I really appreciate your reply sir. But **JustAndrei** posted the answer beforehand thus his answer will be accepted :)

Comment: ya of course, no harm.. glad it worked out eventually... happy programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Firewall should be configured to allow that connection or turned off.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late to answer this post, but I have managed to get communication between my PC and tablet using this project.
I tried many combinations of IP addresses and found that it works only when the IP addresses in the PC NetService (c#) and the Android Communication Client were the same and defined by my own network IP address e.g. "192.168.1.155" in the example given below:
ie. in the c# NetService programme:

IDuplexInputChannel anInputChannel = aMessaging.CreateDuplexInputChannel("tcp://192.168.1.155:4080/");

and in the Android Client programme:

IDuplexOutputChannel anOutputChannel = aMessaging.createDuplexOutputChannel("tcp://192.168.1.155:4080/");

The programme works as described in the article when the tablet is connected by USB to my PC using my home wi-fi for the tablet. 
It also works when the USB is disconnected from the tablet showing that the connection is by wi-fi.
The programme did not work if I used the IPs "10.0.2.2" and "127.0.0.1" in either package.
It also does not work if the tablet is not using the same wi-fi as the PC.